# ‘At a Glance’ dashboard: combining infos

Tags: hooks, dashboard

I add a hook on at a glance dashboard for custom posts and it runs ok. If i add a count users and an other for each, I lost the post_type info.

Also the //second is working well if the //first is over

How can I combine the both?

```
function at_glance() {

//second
    $number_users = count_users();
    $text = $number_users['total_users'];
    $roles = $number_users['avail_roles'];
    
    $items[] = '<a class="users-count" href="users.php">' . $text . ' total users</a>';
    
    foreach( $roles as $role => $count ){   
        if($role == 'none'){
        } else {
        $items[] = '<span><a class="users-count" href="'.admin_url('users.php?role='.$role).'">' . $role . '( ' . $count . ' )</a></span>';
        }
}
return $items;

//first
    $glances = array(); 
    $args = array( 'public'   => true, '_builtin' => false   );
    $post_types = get_post_types($args, 'object', 'and');

    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
        $num_posts = wp_count_posts($post_type->name);
        $num   = number_format_i18n($num_posts->publish);
        $text  = _n($post_type->labels->singular_name, $post_type->labels->name, intval($num_posts->publish));
        if (current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
            $glance = '<a class="'.$post_type->name.'-count" href="'.admin_url('edit.php?post_type='.$post_type->name).'">'.$num.' '.$text.'</a>';
        } else {
            $glance = '<span class="'.$post_type->name.'-count">'.$num.' '.$text.'</span>';
        }
        $glances[] = $glance;
    }
return $glances;
}
add_action('dashboard_glance_items', 'at_glance');
```

At the end, I would like to add other informations (media, tags, ...)

Thx for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dashboard_glance_items`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/dashboard_glance_items/) is a *filter hook*, not *an action hook*. [See here for an explanation of the difference.](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/)

Your `at_glance()` function doesn't include the existing values, so only the items you return will be present in the At A Glance widget items.

Something more like this:

```php
function at_glance( $items ) {
    $number_users = count_users();
    $text = $number_users['total_users'];
    $roles = $number_users['avail_roles'];
    
    $items[] = '<a class="users-count" href="users.php">' . $text . ' total users</a>';
    
    foreach( $roles as $role => $count ){   
        if($role == 'none'){
        } else {
        $items[] = '<span><a class="users-count" href="'.admin_url('users.php?role='.$role).'">' . $role . '( ' . $count . ' )</a></span>';
        }
    }

    $args = array( 'public'   => true, '_builtin' => false   );
    $post_types = get_post_types($args, 'object', 'and');

    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
        $num_posts = wp_count_posts($post_type->name);
        $num   = number_format_i18n($num_posts->publish);
        $text  = _n($post_type->labels->singular_name, $post_type->labels->name, intval($num_posts->publish));
        if (current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
            $glance = '<a class="'.$post_type->name.'-count" href="'.admin_url('edit.php?post_type='.$post_type->name).'">'.$num.' '.$text.'</a>';
        } else {
            $glance = '<span class="'.$post_type->name.'-count">'.$num.' '.$text.'</span>';
        }
        $items[] = $glance;
    }
    return $items;
}

add_filter('dashboard_glance_items', 'at_glance');
```

...*might* be closer to what you're looking for. (I've combined your `//second` and `//first` code, and tried to get it to a point where it won't throw a fatal error.)

Comment: Fantastic. Thx so much. It comes unordered but it shows up. Users are at the middle of the post_types. BTW, the existing values come up as well (pages and articles). And the strange thing is the guest-author (with 0) that appears, I really don't know why. But your solution is working well!